# How does the "Reload" work in react-native when running on a physical android device?

Tags: react-native

When the RN app is run on an android physical devices and the adb is connected over USB how does the "Reload" on the app fetches the files saved on the development project directory. How does the App knows the ip address of the development machine ?

Answer (score 0):

First if you have real device type this code: `react-native run-android --deviceId [YOUR ID]`

If you want debug the app through Wifi you must first find your ip and then in adb type:

```
adb tcpip 5555
adb connect [YOUR IP]
```

Then type  `react-native run-android --deviceId [YOUR ID]` again with your new id ([your device ip]:5555)

For the first time your app will be built. But for reload index.js open dev menu , go to dev setting in Debug server host & port for device type `[YOUR PC IP]:8081`

Answer (score 0):

When the application is started the **react-native run-android ...** command does the reverse(forwarding the ports) of the ports using the following command which is visible in node start logs.

```
adb -s [device_id] reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

So after this when the "RR" command is received by the RN app, it loads the page from the localhost (http://localhost:8081/xyz.js?foo...) which is being forwarded to the development host.